# stripe eventlistener is not a function error

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am trying to pass a postal code value that is obtained through php. I am properly echoing the postal code

```
var myPostalCodeField = "<?php echo $order->billing['postcode']?>";

myPostalCodeField.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    card.update({value: {postalCode: event.target.value}});
});
```

It seems when I looks at the source code of my page that the postcode is properly echoing into the javascript. However I am getting the following error:

```
checkout_confirmationtest.php:757 Uncaught TypeError: myPostalCodeField.addEventListener is not a function
```

I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You should post that source code form the page... It looks like you are probably trying to attach an eventListener to a var of type string in javascript. What about trying card.update({value: {postalCode: <?php echo $order->billing['postcode']?>}});

Comment: Not sure how a string has an event listener. What are you trying to do exactly? Is it an input that relates to the string or are you trying to detect when that variable changes value?